# eBay API findItemsByKeywords operation returns 'Page Limit exceeded. Items can be fetched only for the first 100 pages' error

Tags: json, ebay-api

Using eBay API (`findItemsByKeywords` operation) to get items details I found that I only get paginated items up to page number 100, so if I need items that are from page 101 I can not get them.

The `findItemsByKeywords` operation return the following error:

```
{"error":[{"errorId":["61"],"domain":["Marketplace"],"severity":["Error"],"category":["Request"],"message":["Page Limit exceeded. Items can be fetched only for the first 100 pages.."]
```

An idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the [documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByKeywords.html#Request.pageNumber) you cannot paginate past 100 pages. You may want to look at increasing the number of items returned per page (100 maximum!) or use a combination of [item filters](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByKeywords.html#Request.itemFilter) and [aspect filters](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByKeywords.html#Request.aspectFilter) to refine the search and reduce the amount of items returned.